# How to retrieve result in periodically run task using Callable

Tags: java, callable, scheduledexecutorservice

How to retrieve result from the task that is run periodically (every n seconds)? The result is needed in further processing. And the task should run forever (as a service, until service is deactivated). I am not using Spring.

Since only Callable returns result, I have to use this method: `schedule (Callable task, long delay, TimeUnit timeunit)`, not `scheduleAtFixedRate` method, and place it in indefinite `while(true)` loop. Is there a better solution? The problem is in retrieving the result from periodically run task.

```
public class DemoScheduledExecutorUsage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = null;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    while (true) {
        scheduledFuture =
            scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    //...some processing done in anothe method
                    String result = "Result retrievd.";
                    return reult;
                }
            },
            10,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            //result 
            System.out.println("result = " + scheduledFuture.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }       
    //Stop in Deactivate method
    //scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: Reopened from duplicate because the linked duplicate discusses running a task periodically but nothing about the core of this question, which is how to retrieve a result from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) included in the JRE.
Using an infinite while loop is IMO not the best idea. Your program will run forever and you have no chance to terminate it.